# adding key to map function is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am currently trying to add a key to my map. However, when I try and give it an index, it then shows up with persons as undefined. Where it was working before. Here is what I have done.

```
   <div className='UserAdminCardsGrid'>
          {personValues.map(person, index =>
            <div key={index} className="UserAdminCard Card">
              <b>Name:</b>
              <div>{person.name}</div>
              <b>ID:</b>
              <div>{person.id}</div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Where is "persons" that is undefined? Do you mean `person`?

Answer (score 5):

It is a wrong syntax

```
personValues.map(person, index =>
```

Wrap the arguments in parentheses

```
personValues.map((person, index) =>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add parenthesis in the arrow function:

```
  <div className='UserAdminCardsGrid'>
       personValues.map((person, index) =>
            <div key={index} className="UserAdminCard Card">
              <b>Name:</b>
              <div>{person.name}</div>
              <b>ID:</b>
              <div>{person.id}</div>
            </div>
       )}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your argument in parenthesis or use object id

wrapping and using map function index

```
personValues.map((person, index) =>
```

or use object id as a key (Recommended to use)

```
{personValues.map(person =>
  <div key={person.id} className="UserAdminCard Card">
   <b>Name:</b>
   <div>{person.name}</div>
   <b>ID:</b>
   <div>{person.id}</div>
   </div>
 )}
```

**Index as a key is an anti-pattern**

> It may break your application and display the wrong data!

refer to [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)
 article for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div className='UserAdminCardsGrid'>
          {personValues.map(({id, name}) =>
            <div key={id} className="UserAdminCard Card">
              <b>Name:</b>
              <div>{name}</div>
              <b>ID:</b>
              <div>{id}</div>
            </div>
         )}
  </div>
```